# Как защитить метод от несуществующого id которое идет с url?

Tags: java, url, spring-security, controller

```
@GetMapping("/api/category/{id}")
@PreAuthorize(value = "(@categoryServiceImpl.getCategoryById(#id)) != null ")
public ResponseEntity<CategoryLinkDTO> getCategoryById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Category category = categoryService.getCategoryById(id);
    Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(CategoryController.class).getCategoryById(category.getId())).withRel("category");
    CategoryLinkDTO publicDTO = DTOBuilder.buildDtoForEntity(category, CategoryLinkDTO.class, selfLink);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(publicDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Я сделал, но тут идут 2 запроса в базу

```
@PreAuthorize(value = "(@categoryServiceImpl.getCategoryById(#id)) != null ")
Category category = categoryService.getCategoryById(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы делаете это в аннотации? 
Почему бы не проверить на null прямо в методе и если сущности с таким id нет то отреагировать соответствующе.